# Mac (Linux) - Restore file removed through mv command

Tags: linux, macos, bash, unix, mv

I have one big problem. I had two files - main.c and logic.c. I have used sed for some modification in logic.c and then i saved it to main_updated.c and then run

```
mv main_updated.c main.c
```

BUT it had to be logic_updated.c and logic.c.
PLS can anyone hlp me, how restore main.c file or i am dead.

Comment: This question is not a programming question; it is more suitable for either [SU] or maybe [Unix.SE].

Comment: I don't suppose you were using a version control system...?

Comment: sorry, move it pleas if someone can

Comment: Fatal: I do one commit to git, but that was in halb of my work on main.c :(

Comment: OS X is not Linux.

Answer (score 2):

Chances are very likely that your old data is gone.  It really depends on how the filesystem works when it comes to overwriting data - if the filesystem simply releases the inodes and allocates new ones elsewhere on the drive, you may be able to use a recovery program to find the data... maybe - you'd have to know where to look since it would probably return a bunch of inodes (and it may not know which ones contained all the data for your files, so you'd have to piece it together manually).

Lesson learned - commit after (most) every change ;P

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you have in fact clobbered your main.c file.

In the future you can use mv "interactively" with:

```
mv -i filename new_filename/or_path
```

It will check with you before overwriting a file.

Also frequent commits with your version control software is a good idea.

Comment: Most distros seem to have aliases confgured for shells, such as `alias mv mv -i` to have a call to mv automatically include interactive mode.

Comment: @up: my experience is that most distros do NOT alias these by default.